# pyspark dataframe map function return type?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

pyspark 2.2
As an exercise to understand how to use map with my own python functions I created this contrived requirement.  Get all databases, and use map to run show tables for each database and collect into a dataframe of all databases and tables.  I realize there is a SparkSession.catalog method to help with this, but I am trying to learn more generally how to use map.

```
# create a function to return a dataframe of tables for each database
def get_tables(database_nm):
  '''get rows of tables in a database and return dataframe of
    database:string
    tableName:string
    isTemporary:boolean
  '''
  return spark.sql("show tables in {0}".format(database_nm))

 dbs_df = spark.sql("show databases")

dbs_df.select('databaseName').rdd.flatMap(lambda x:(get_tables(x))).take(5)
```

My guess is that returning a dataframe from my function is not correct.  If so, what types can I return?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `spark.sql("show tables in {0}".format(database_nm))`, you're effectively instructing spark to parse and execute the string as a SQL statement in its own SQL implementation. This works with temporary tables that you create from data frames created in Spark.

Additionally, `"show tables in {0}".format(database_nm)"` is a kind of admin command or non-standard SQL likely supported by your own RDBMS vendor. This won't work in spark.

According to [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases), this is how you create a data frame that loads data from a SQL data source (using jdbc):

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
  .option("user", "username") \
  .option("password", "password") \
  .load()
```

You would need to understand how the database connection properties are passed to Spark and that, as far as this goes, you load information from tables/views.

If your RDBMS exposes views for metadata (such as Oracle's data dictionary), you should be able to retrieve the list of tables using something like:

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dbserver:PORT/databasename") \
  .option("dbtable", "sys.ALL_TABLES") \
  .option("user", "username") \
  .option("password", "password") \
  .load()
```

This is a dataset you can collect and further generate dynamic data frames from.